# Unmanaged Packages

Tags: managed-package, package, unmanaged-package

I have an assignment to check pros & cons of managed and unmanaged packages. It's the first time i get into this part. I investigated pros & cons and in my dev org i created an unmanaged package. Then, i uploaded it. Afterwards, from another dev org i went there and installed the package i just created. It doesn't contain something special, just 1 custom object. The problem is that, it it showing in number of objects: 0. And when i drill down to the object, it redirects me to Object Manager. Is this logical ? I feel that maybe i do something wrong.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest an [edit] here as you have two different questions in one (the # of objects in package, metadata migration). Question #2 is also pretty open-ended and a little opinion-based as there's no "best" solution given we don't know your org specifics. You may want to remove question 2 and ask it with more focus as a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefit of managed packages is that they can be upgraded. You can add new content to them, and those changes can be applied with a simple update. The downside to managed packages is that they have restrictions on deleting metadata from them, so it becomes very important to design your application beforehand, lest you end up with lots of stuff you can't delete. Some care also needs to be taken to not accidentally link the package to another package or unwanted metadata for the same reason. It's nearly impossible to fix these mistakes.

Unmanaged packages can be freely modified, even after installation (e.g. someone an install your package, then delete a field). The downside is that you cannot upgrade those packages. They must be fully uninstalled and reinstalled to apply a new version. This is problematic in many cases, as you need to make sure that you have all the metadata you need in one shot, and making changes is easy, but non-trivial to fix in orgs where the package is installed.

You may want to look at Unlocked Packages. They have the editability of unmanaged packages, and the upgradeability of managed packages. This would require moving to DX, which is not terribly difficult, but will take a little bit of time.

Everything is migrating to Lightning, so I'm not surprised that clicking on the object name takes you to Object Manager. The "zero objects" bit may just a bug of some sort. There's clearly one object in the package.